# magento2 image add in pdf how to? this code not working for me

Tags: magento2, product, image, pdf

$post = $this->getRequest()->getParam('sku');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$helperImport = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
$productRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
$productObj = $productRepository->get($post);
$sku = $productObj->getSku();
$name = $productObj->getName();
$price =  $productObj->getPrice();
$description = $productObj->getDescription();
$shortDescripton = $productObj->getShortDescription();
$imageUrl = $helperImport->init($productObj, 'product_page_image_small')
->setImageFile($productObj->getSmallImage())
->resize(380)
->getUrl();

```
    $pdf = new \Zend_Pdf();
    $pdf->pages[] = $pdf->newPage(\Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
    $page = $pdf->pages[0]; // this will get reference to the first page.
    $style = new \Zend_Pdf_Style();
    $style->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0,0,0));
    $font = \Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES);
    $style->setFont($font,15);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $width = $page->getWidth();
    $hight = $page->getHeight();
    $x = 30;
    $pageTopalign = 700; 
    $this->y = 700 - 100; 
    
    $style->setFont($font,15);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y + 10, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y +70, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);
    
    $style->setFont($font,15);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawText(__("Product Attribute Information"), $x + 5, $this->y+50, 'UTF-8');
    $style->setFont($font,11);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    //$page->drawText(__("Name : %1", "Test MageDelight"), $x + 5, $this->y+33, 'UTF-8');
   // $page->drawText(__("Email : %1","test@magedelight.com"), $x + 4, $this->y+15, 'UTF-8');
    $style->setFont($font,11);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $page->drawText(__("Image"), $x + 60, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("Sku"), $x + 60, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("Product Name"), $x + 200, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("Price"), $x + 310, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("Description"), $x + 440, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText(__("ShortDescription"), $x + 440, $this->y-10, 'UTF-8');
    $style->setFont($font,10);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    $add = 9;
    $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $fileSystem = $om->create('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem');
    $pdfImage =$fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath("catalog/product".$productObj->getImage());

    $image =  \Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($pdfImage);


   
    $page->drawImage($image, $x + 210, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText($name, $x + 210, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText($price, $x + 330, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText($description, $x + 470, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawText($sku, $x + 65, $this->y-30, 'UTF-8');
    $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y -62, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y + 10, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);
    $page->drawRectangle(30, $this->y -62, $page->getWidth()-30, $this->y - 100, \Zend_Pdf_Page::SHAPE_DRAW_STROKE);
    $style->setFont($font,15);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    //$page->drawText(__("Total : %1", "$50.00"), $x + 435, $this->y-85, 'UTF-8');
    $style->setFont($font,10);
    $page->setStyle($style);
    //$page->drawText(__("Test Footer example"), ($page->getWidth()/2)-50, $this->y-200);
    $fileName = 'attribute.pdf';
    $this->fileFactory->create(
       $fileName,
       $pdf->render(),
       \Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
       'application/pdf'
    );
```

Comment: May I know which version you are using it?

Comment: magento2.4.3 php 7.4